# Encountering Problems with Stanford CoreNLP OpenIE

Tags: stanford-nlp

I've been having some issues trying to use Stanford CoreNLP OpenIE. I followed the example at http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/openie.shtml, and I found I had the issues described in [Stanford OpenIE with option openie.resolve_coref don't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35921678/stanford-openie-with-option-openie-resolve-coref-dont-work#).

So, I followed the instruction to utilize the GitHub version, and downloaded the models from the GitHub link too. I compiled using ant and I then built the jar files as the GitHub page instructed. I then added the jar files I needed from this to the build path of a new project.

Testing the OpenIEDemo with this not only has the same problem as before, but the program now doesn't end without me forcing it to (it's worth pointing out that this isn't just the demo, but also a class I created which has separate method calls etc). Executing the code seems to execute all lines of code in the main, but it doesn't end afterwards.

So, my questions are,

1) is the bug described in [Stanford OpenIE with option openie.resolve_coref don't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35921678/stanford-openie-with-option-openie-resolve-coref-dont-work#) still an issue even on the current GitHub version, and if not what on earth am I doing wrong?

2) Was something changed in the way the stanford CoreNLP code is run in order for it not to automatically end? (It appears to happen any time a StanfordCoreNLP object is created, whether it is used or not). If not, how can i fix this? (I can of course manually cause the program to end with System.exit(), but I'd rather not be doing that). - this only occurs using the GitHub jars.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding CoreNLP not exiting: this is a bug I recently introduced with a thread cleaning up unused annotators not being set as daemon. This is fixed as of a few minutes ago, and should hit GitHub soon.

Regarding coref not working: I couldn't replicate the bug -- I still get the output I do in my answer to [the previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35921678/stanford-openie-with-option-openie-resolve-coref-dont-work/36024504#36024504). The clauses in the sentence do not resolve coref (this is intended behavior), but the triples produced do. For example, in *Obama was born in Hawaii. He is our president*, we will extract a clause *He be president*, but extract the triple `(Obama; be; president)`.